# VirtualBox is complaining that kernel module is not loaded after vagrant up run

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I tried to run `vagrant up` command in linux terminal then facing these following errors :

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:


VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

I also run `VBoxManage --version` but it still getting these following errors:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (5.0.0-32-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
    6.0.14r133895
```

**I found some question on this site but still not getting any solutions.**

Comment: DId you try to compile new kernel module?

Comment: yes I tried but its failed

Comment: Please add error in to the question

Comment: my problem is solved I answer my own question Btw thanks@RomeoNinov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was in the virtual box.

I run `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*` this command this to remove all the vb files then upgraded to latest version by downloaded `.deb` [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) files.